# Yii2: Sending params with Anchor as POST request

Tags: post, parameters, yii2

I try to get `POST` Variables in my controller from view with:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider_products,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                    [
                        'label'=>'Name',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value'=>function ($data) use ($model, $dataProvider_products) {
                            return Html::a($data['name'],['suppliers_orders/addproduct', 'order' => $model->id, 'product' => $data['id'],
                                'data-method'=> 'post',
                                'data-params' => ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider_products],
                                ]);
                        },
                    ],
                    'supplier_product_number',
                    'size',
                    'price_net',
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

The parameter `dataProvider` will always be sent with the `URL` and results in a `GET` variable. What is wrong, respectively what must be done, that `dataProvider` will be sent as `POST` variable?

Part of my controller is:

```
public function actionAddproduct($order, $product){

// look for GET variable
$request = Yii::$app->request->get('data');
$dataProvider = $request['params']['dataProvider'];

// look for POST variable
$param1 = Yii::$app->request->post('dataProvider', null);

$dataProvider_suppliers_orders_products = $dataProvider;

return $this->actionView($order);

}
```

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out.

Comment: add the controller action where you are trying to vet these params

Comment: You are trying to post the `$dataProvider` object you cant do that why are you posting the `$dataprovider` object and above all even with this you should still be able to receive the parameter although it would show you `[Object Object]` which is not what you want. what is the version of the framework you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are passing the `data-params` in the `url` parameter rather than setting in the `options` parameter, so yes it will always be sent as query string no matter you pull your hairs off and become bald **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**.

Then According to the [**`DOCS`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#generating-tags)

> If the attribute is a data attribute as listed in
>   **`yii\helpers\Html::$dataAttributes`**, such as `data` or `ng`, a list of
>   attributes will be rendered, one for each element in the value array.
>   For example, `'data' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'yii']` generates
>   `data-id="1" data-name="yii"` and `'data' => ['params' => ['id' => 1,
>   'name' => 'yii'], 'status' => 'ok']` generates
>   `data-params='{"id":1,"name":"yii"}' data-status="ok"`

So, you need to change the anchor to look like

```
Html::a($data['name'], ['suppliers_orders/addproduct', 'order' => $model->id, 'product' => $data['id']], [
    'data' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'params' => ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider_products]
    ]
]);
```

**But since you are passing the `$dataProvider` object to the params it aint going to work because it will be changed to `[Object Object]` but if it is simple text then it will work, otherwise you have to change your approach.**

Your complete code for the `GridView` should look like below

```
    <?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider_products,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data) use ($model, $dataProvider_products) {
                return Html::a($data['name'], ['suppliers_orders/addproduct', 'order' => $model->id, 'product' => $data['id']], [
                            'data' => [
                                'method' => 'POST',
                                'params' => ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider_products]
                            ]
                ]);
            },
        ],
        'supplier_product_number',
        'size',
        'price_net',
    ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: In the first step I tried it also like you recommended, but no POST variable in controller. I did it now again, still no luck, no POST variable!

Comment: add the controller action where you are trying to vet these params

Comment: I look at the debugger and I can see there is no POST. My controller will catch the POST variable with $param1 = Yii::$app->request->post('dataProvider', null);

Comment: please can you add the `action` , i understand but i just replicated and tested that's why asking to add the action code in your Question, i cant guess without seeing where is the mistake it runs correctly at my end  @Perino

Comment: above all you are sending `$dataProvider_products` is it the model object you are posting? @Perino , you cant do that

Comment: I added now the controller function. Yes, it is the model object of an additional model in the view. I try to realize an order form where it is possible to add the order items in the same view. Therefore I open a modal window, select an order item and call the controller function actionAddproduct. With the help of Pjax I update my order items in the main view. For this I need the model object of the selected order item.

Comment: i dont think you would be able to do that. how are you going to use the object it wont be usable anyhow even if you start receiving it in the `POST` var. what i am trying to understand is that you are saying that i select the item and call the function you mean you click on the link against that item and you want that item to be added to some other `form` ? are you opening the gridview in side the modal window and trying to add the item in the form which is actually in the `view` from where you opened the modal window for `GridView` ?

Comment: Yes there is the main order form with some details which will be shown in a DetailView. Additionally I have a GridView in the same view, which should show the product items belonging to this order. With a button 'addProduct' a modal window opens, where I can choose a product. With clicking the link of the item in den modal window, the product will be chosen and the controller function actionAddproduct in the controller of the main order form called. At the end of the function the GridView for the items in the main order form will be updated via Pjax.

Comment: okay and the products that are already added to the order are they coming from a `database table` or `session`? @Perino

Comment: From database table! Your are right, it is not possible to send object via POST. Finally I got [object Object] as POST variable. I think, I have to look for a different approach.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was talking about, you should select the answer @Perino i have updated the information in it.